# How can I drop installing debug_inspector gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I'm starting a new test rails project with **RubyMine** and I can't bundle install an empty project and **debug inspector** gem failed to be built with native extension. I don't want this gem I use **byebug** instead and it's not in my **Gemfile**. why does it have to be installed every time I 'bundle install' and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are good that some other gem depend on the `debug_inspector`. And I guess that's the `web-console` dependency.

Comment: so, should I remove the web-console gem ? I don't know what it does ?

Comment: Yes, removing it will should fix the issue with debug_inspector. The web console allows you to access ruby console from rails error pages, it's not especially useful actually.